# JavaFx and Floating button

Tags: java, css, javafx, material-design, pane

I have a problem with a GUI made in JavaFX, you can see the gui [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY1zx.png).

As you can see there is a center pane with Cards and an action Button on the right bottom edge of the GUI, i realized this effect with this piece fo code

```
public class MainFrame extends BorderPane{         

private Header header   = new Header();
private Sidebar sidebar = new Sidebar();   
private GhostAbsolutePane ghostPaneWithPlay = new GhostAbsolutePane();   
private HomePane homePane                      = new HomePane();

private final StackPane mainPane = new StackPane();

   public MainFrame() {         
        mainPane.getStyleClass().add("main-stack-pane");
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(homePane, ghostPaneWithPlay);            

        this.setTop(header);
        this.setLeft(sidebar);
        this.setCenter(mainPane);                
    }                                  
}
```

I have filled the center of the MainFrame with a StackPane where the first child contains a pane with the cards in a GridBagLayout and the second child is a generic pane made like that

```
public class GhostAbsolutePane extends Region{

    private Button run = new Button("");

    private double diameter = 56;

    public GhostAbsolutePane() {

        run.setMinWidth(diameter);
        run.setMaxWidth(diameter);

        run.setMinHeight(diameter);
        run.setMaxHeight(diameter);

        this.getChildren().add(run);

        this.setMouseTransparent(true);

        this.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)->{
            onResize();
        });

        this.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)->{
            onResize();
        }); 

    }

    private void onResize(){
        double h = getHeight();
        double w = getWidth();

        run.setTranslateX(w-diameter);
        run.setTranslateY(h-diameter);
    }        
}
```

The problem is simple. If I set to the pane `ghostPaneWithPlay` the `setMouseTransparent` property to `true` I can interact with the cards but I cannot hit the button; otherwise I can hit the button but cannot interact with the cards.

How can I avoid this unwanted behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to place the “Play” button (the circular button with ▶) in the lower right corner.

You should not be using StackPane for this.  Just use a BorderPane, and let it handle the positioning:

```
private final BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

// ...

    Button playButton = new Button("\u25b6");
    playButton.getStyleClass().add("play");

    mainPane.setCenter(homePane);
    HBox buttonPane = new HBox(12, playButton);
    buttonPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    mainPane.setBottom(buttonPane);
```

Comment: Wow, really nice trick!!
But I want that in case of resizing the button could go over the cards, is it possible?

Comment: My guess is that your HomePane is using hard-coded sizes, so things cannot shrink to accommodate a smaller window.  Instead of forcing the size of each section in the HomePane, let them be their natural sizes and place them in a vertical [FlowPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/FlowPane.html), so resizing of the window will be handled gracefully.

Comment: The home pane is a HBox containing some VBox